# How can I use my applet on popular mobile devices?

Tags: android, applet, nfc, smartcard, two-factor-authentication

I have a website that uses an applet and corresponding server-side API to authenticate users with a smart card and contact-less card reader.

The solution works fine on a desktop environment, however, I would like to take advantage of the NFC capability of Android phones (and hopefully also iPhone 6 onwards). The card is read just fine by these phones. The issue is that the applet will not run on these devices.

What are my options? Can you somehow wrap the applet in some other technology? Are there 3rd party apps or alternative browsers that allow for this? If I do have the functionality redeveloped into something else that can run client-side, what technology would I be looking at?

Comment: Just to be sure: you are talking about plain old Java applets (small apps running in your browser), not about Java Card applets (running on smartcard), right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry my question was ambiguous. It is not a java card, it is a mifare (forget the exact version but it is not a classic). The applet is indeed on the site (although it does run on the client PC precisely because otherwise you can't interact with the smart card from the remote web server)

Comment: Android and iOS will never support applets.  Most desktop based browsers are either severely limiting applets, or in the case of Chrome, planning to completely remove support for them.  Recode the applet in HTML/JS if you want to support mobile platforms (and a lot less head-aches with the desktop browsers).

Comment: Can JS provide secure smartcard authentication though? Check certificates, sign with them, etc